# Is it possible to control the destination folder when checking out a project from VSS 2005?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-sourcesafe, visual-sourcesafe-2005

We are currently using VSS 2005 for source control - and please let me start by saying, I've read a lot of posts on Stackoverflow and I realize VSS is the devil.  That being said... its what we have to work with now and I have a question about the checkout process.  We have the code organized in a certain hierarchy on the vss server, but when we do a checkout we don't need that same hierarchy on our machines.  Is there a way to control how visual studio 2008 and vss 2005 create the checkout destination folder so that I don't end up with the code being 9 folders deep on MY machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in VSS you can manually associate different parts of the VSS hierarchy to different paths (IIRC, right click, "set working folder").

You can also just get the parts you want instead of getting or updating directly from $/